# Forcing localhost to use https results in a 403 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, xampp, http-status-code-403

I am working on a php website. I am working on it using Aptana with XAMPP. I recently changed my htaccess file to force my site to use https on the localhost. I haven't yet implemented a ssl certificate. When I try to access a webpage now, I am directed to a page that says:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL 
manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.6.3 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I found some solutions to this but I really want to know why this is occurring. I know that I can change the httpd.conf file to fix it but I still don't understand what is happening.

Comment: If HTTPS is not configured (i.e. a port bound to a cert) then HTTPS will not work.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That answers my question.